# how get image from external source url in detail page

Tags: magento2, product-images

I'm using magento 2.3,
I need to use external link for img not uploaded in magento end for product Detail page

Answer (score 0):

1. Create product input attribute.
2. Save the product image url link into that input attribute.
3. Get attribute value in product page & set that url into image src.